# Presentation of Research Hypotheses (APA 6th)

Tags: writing-style

How is the research hypotheses presented in a qualitative research?

For example, the statement of the problem is stated this way:

The study generally aims to -----. Specifically, it seeks to find answers to the following questions:

1. 
2. 
3. 

Now, I'm wondering how a research hypotheses should be presented

Comment: I can't help with an answer, but am a bit confused about the context. Are you in the early stages of the research, formulating the questions? Are you writing the dissertation now? Or a publication based on the dissertation? This might help generate a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware APA style does not have specific formatting for problem statements or hypothesis. The [APA Example paper](http://www.apastyle.org/manual/related/sample-experiment-paper-1.pdf) lacks a clear *problem statement* and has a paragraph that describes what was done.

> In the current research, therefore, we compared young and older adults’ detection of four 
>   categories of emotional information (positive high arousal, positive low arousal, negative high 
>   arousal, and negative low arousal) with their detection of neutral information. The positive and 
>   negative stimuli were carefully matched on arousal level, and the categories of high and low 
>   arousal were closely matched on valence to assure that the factors of valence (positive, negative) 
>   and arousal (high, low) could be investigated independently of one another...

Comment: Can I present it this way:

This study will test the following hypotheses:

a.

b.

Comment: Or should I present my hypotheses in paragraph form like this: The researchers hypothesized that… (All hypotheses are stated in a paragraph without explanation)

Comment: @Janjan according to APA style you can do whatever you want as long as you don't break any other their other rules. It sounds like you are writing something for a class, in which case as your teacher.

Comment: Our instructor told us to not use bullets when stating the hypotheses. Could I then still use this format This study will test the following hypotheses: a. b.

Comment: @Janjan your instructor is imposing additional rules beyond those specified in APA 6. There is no way for us to know what is acceptable. Ask you instructor for further guidance.